# How to remove the cassandra node from failuredetector

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I used the `nodetool decommission` command to remove a node from the cassandra cluster. Then I used the `nodetool status` command to see that the node was successfully removed, but using the `nodetool failuredetector` command, I can see that the removed node is still in the Endpoint and the value of Phi Continue to increase. How do I remove the node from the failuredetector?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the node is still in gossip, or it could be left over in one of the nodes' `system.peers` table.  Running a `nodetool assassinate` on that node should fully-remove it.

```
nodetool assassinate <IP_ADDRESS>
```